# Storing a **pointer returned by another function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, return-value

I have a function loadmap() that basically loads a grid from a file. In it I dynamically create an array of integers called 'mapa'.

```
int loadmap(int *n) {
  int i, j;
  int **mapa;
  int num;
  char space;
  int count = 0;
  FILE *f;
  f = fopen(SUBOR, "r");

  fscanf(f, "%d%c", &num, &space);
  while (space != '\n') {
    count++;
    fscanf(f, "%d%c", &num, &space);
  }

  mapa = (int **)malloc(pocet * sizeof(int *));
  for (i = 0; i < pocet; i++) {
    mapa[i] = (int *)malloc(pocet * sizeof(int));
  }

  rewind(f);

  for (i = 0; i < pocet; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < pocet; j++) {
      fscanf(f, "%d%c", &num, &space);
      mapa[i][j] = num;
    }
  }

  *n = count;

  return **mapa;
}
```

Then in the main I'd like to use that returned pointer to the array as an argument for other functions. I tried storing it in all kinds of variables I could think of but nothing works. Here is what I have now.

```
int main() {
  int **mapa;
  int n;
  int ki, kj;

  **mapa = loadmap(&n);
  printf("rozmer stvorcovej mapy: %d\n", n);
  najdi_kopec(mapa, n, &ki, &kj);
  printf("suradnice kopca: %d, %d\n", ki, kj);
  zidi_kopec(mapa, n, ki, kj);

  return 0;
}
```

I think this get's me closest to the solution because it works with how the rest of the program needs to be written, but this produces **'uninitialized local variable 'mapa' used ' error** . I'm not sure if I'm using the correct aproach, I'm just starting with C. Could you please suggest some tweak to make what I have work or another working approach altogether?

Thanks

--------- EDIT ------------

adding declarations of other functions

---

```
void najdi_kopec(int **mapa, int n, int *ki, int *kj) {
  int i, j;
  *ki = *kj = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
      if (mapa[i][j] > mapa[*ki][*kj]) {
        *ki = i;
        *kj = j;
        // printf("i: %d, j: %d, mapa: %d\n", *ki, *kj, mapa[*ki][*kj]);
      }
}
```

---

```
void zidi_kopec(int **mapa, int n, int ki, int kj) {
  int i, j, max;
  while (ki != 0 && ki != n - 1 && kj != 0 && kj != n - 1) {
    max = 0;
    // sever
    if (ki - 1 >= 0 && mapa[ki - 1][kj] > max &&
        mapa[ki - 1][kj] < mapa[ki][kj]) {
      i = ki - 1;
      j = kj;
      max = mapa[i][j];
    }

    // vychod
    if (kj + 1 < n && mapa[ki][kj + 1] > max &&
        mapa[ki][kj + 1] < mapa[ki][kj]) {
      i = ki;
      j = kj + 1;
      max = mapa[i][j];
    }
    // juh
    if (ki + 1 < n && mapa[ki + 1][kj] > max &&
        mapa[ki + 1][kj] < mapa[ki][kj]) {
      i = ki + 1;
      j = kj;
      max = mapa[i][j];
    }
    // zapad
    if (kj - 1 >= 0 && mapa[ki][kj - 1] > max &&
        mapa[ki][kj - 1] < mapa[ki][kj]) {
      i = ki;
      j = kj - 1;
      max = mapa[i][j];
    }
    printf("i: %d, j: %d, vyska: %d\n", i, j, max);
    ki = i;
    kj = j;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just `return mapa;`, then make corresponding changes in `main`.

Comment: This seem invalid btw `**mapa = nacitaj_mapu(&n);`. Where do you call that loadmap? And you should return `int**` not just simple `int`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm i get "return value type does not match the function type"

Comment: @Eraklon right sorry, forgot to translate that bit, that's the loadmap() just transalted for a bit of context

Comment: @Eraklon could you clarify a bit please? I'm not sure how I'd do that. If it's just return mapa, then that gives me an "return value type does not match the function type" error

Comment: just make your function like `int** looadm...` and `return mapa` not `**mapa`.

Comment: Never cast the result of a call to `malloc()` etc. It is unnecessary, and can mask the serious bug of a missing valid prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration of loadmap() should be `int ** loadmap(int *n)` if you want to return a double pointer `mapa`, and the return value is `mapa` instead of `** mapa`.

In the main function, you declared a double pointer `mapa`, but when you call `loadmap()` function, you just take the first value that `mapa` points to. So, if you use `mapa` on another function as the argument, `mapa` was not initialized because we did not allocate this pointer (using `malloc` for example).

Your code is not proper. You have to post other functions here.

UPDATED:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int pocet = 5;
#define SUBOR "text.txt"
int ** loadmap(int *n) {
  int i, j;
  int **mapa;
  int num;
  char space;
  int count = 0;
  FILE *f;
  f = fopen(SUBOR, "r");
  if (!f) 
    exit(-1);
  fscanf(f, "%d%c", &num, &space);
  while (space != '\n') {
    count++;
    fscanf(f, "%d%c", &num, &space);
  }

  mapa = (int **)malloc(pocet * sizeof(int *));
  for (i = 0; i < pocet; i++) {
    mapa[i] = (int *)malloc(pocet * sizeof(int));
  }

  rewind(f);

  for (i = 0; i < pocet; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < pocet; j++) {
      fscanf(f, "%d%c", &num, &space);
      mapa[i][j] = num;
    }
  }

  *n = count;

  return mapa;
}

void najdi_kopec(int **mapa, int n, int *ki, int *kj) {
  int i, j;
  *ki = *kj = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
      if (mapa[i][j] > mapa[*ki][*kj]) {
        *ki = i;
        *kj = j;
        // printf("i: %d, j: %d, mapa: %d\n", *ki, *kj, mapa[*ki][*kj]);
      }
}

void zidi_kopec(int **mapa, int n, int ki, int kj) {
  int i, j, max;
  while (ki != 0 && ki != n - 1 && kj != 0 && kj != n - 1) {
    max = 0;
    // sever
    if (ki - 1 >= 0 && mapa[ki - 1][kj] > max &&
        mapa[ki - 1][kj] < mapa[ki][kj]) {
      i = ki - 1;
      j = kj;
      max = mapa[i][j];
    }

    // vychod
    if (kj + 1 < n && mapa[ki][kj + 1] > max &&
        mapa[ki][kj + 1] < mapa[ki][kj]) {
      i = ki;
      j = kj + 1;
      max = mapa[i][j];
    }
    // juh
    if (ki + 1 < n && mapa[ki + 1][kj] > max &&
        mapa[ki + 1][kj] < mapa[ki][kj]) {
      i = ki + 1;
      j = kj;
      max = mapa[i][j];
    }
    // zapad
    if (kj - 1 >= 0 && mapa[ki][kj - 1] > max &&
        mapa[ki][kj - 1] < mapa[ki][kj]) {
      i = ki;
      j = kj - 1;
      max = mapa[i][j];
    }
    printf("i: %d, j: %d, vyska: %d\n", i, j, max);
    ki = i;
    kj = j;
  }
}

int main() {
  int **mapa;
  int n;
  int ki, kj;

  mapa = loadmap(&n);
  printf("rozmer stvorcovej mapy: %d\n", n);
  najdi_kopec(mapa, n, &ki, &kj);
  printf("suradnice kopca: %d, %d\n", ki, kj);
  zidi_kopec(mapa, n, ki, kj);

  return 0;
}
```

`text.txt` likes:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5
```

The result when i test as below:

```
rozmer stvorcovej mapy: 5
suradnice kopca: 1, 0
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how the main() should look please? I changed the function loadmap type and return value like you suggested but i still can't seem to get it working properly.

Comment: what is problem when you updated the `loadmap` function ? can you show the declarations of other functions, for example,  `najdi_kopec, zidi_kopec` ?

Comment: i dont know exactly, what you want, because you dont write or comment the code by english. I just changed a bit your code, then it works

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot! Also sorry about the code, I'll have to take better care of that in the future.